# Has Google Chrome Very Recently Changed Textarea Functionality?

Tags: google-chrome, textarea

Just today, all the textareas in websites I wrote for my personal use, hosted ON/IN my Notebook are showing wavy red lines whenever I cut and paste text into them. I absolutely have not changed anything in those scripts!!! Haven't been near the .ini files of Apache nor PHP for months, the current stack is reliable and stable.

Has anyone else noticed a similar change? Is it in fact Google throwing their bully weight around and invading my website(s)?

Tested Firefox and it is not screwing around with my website's textarea content, compose a
few lines:

"Haven't been near the .ini files /..."

"I frequently choose to create neo~ologisms and emply SATIRICAL spelling in my personal writing and in my code, and it is very veryillee annnoying to have suddenly, all that goddamn red splashed all over the page."

Drop those onto a textarea of a website [to be clear: on my notebook/localhost] within
Firefox, and no wavy lines trashing " .ini " and the deliberate misspellings and the
neologisms in those lines.  But as of today, drop those lines onto the same textarea with
the website being viewed using Chrome, and this changed and unwelcome behaviour shows up.

If anyone has recently encountered this phenomena, the real question (since it is unlikely
to change if it IS a change in Chrome) what might I do, code~wise, to negate it?  Write a script to somehow turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the spellchecking feature of Chrome. If you want to disable spellchecking for a textarea or input element on your site, use [the spellcheck attribute,](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#spelling-and-grammar-checking) for example:

```
<textarea spellcheck="false">
</textarea>
```

This will disable the red underlines in Chrome for all users of your site.

You can also turn off spellcheck in Chrome. Exactly how to do it unfortunately varies on Windows, OS X, Linux and so on. On OS X, for example, I think you can turn the red underlines off by Ctrl-clicking in a text area, then selecting Spelling and Grammar, and unchecking Check Spelling While Typing.

Comment: @ Dominic Cooney  Man, that is good news.  Now go through a few dozen sites' scripts and run a function to add that attribute & setting.  I had previously set Chrome's spell~checking to OFF, but until yesterday Chrome was treating text pasted in as though it had been typed in... so with spell~check set to OFF, that was okay.  Now it appears to no longer respect the USER Specified *no spell~check*